# Disabling local cursor when using Guacamole VNC

Tags: vnc, guacamole

I'm using Guacamole VNC web client viewer and I want to hide the local browser cursor, because otherwise you see two cursors and it is confusing.

I can hide the browser mouse using simple style: cursor:none;
But this is not so good because when some connection exception occurs, I need the browser mouse in order to close the error window etc.

Any solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is to hide the remote cursor not the local one. The VNC protocol allows you to hide the remote cursor. Most VNC clients support this. For example, in [noVNC](https://github.com/kanaka/noVNC) (a HTML5 VNC client) there is a "Local Cursor" option to hide the remote cursor so that you only see one cursor.

Unfortunatley, you can't do this right now in Guacamole. There is a long standing bug in Guacamole to add this support: http://guac-dev.org/trac/ticket/33

**Update:** the option has been fixed in Guacamole.

Comment: Thanks. I Finally did use the cursor:none only when the connection is working and disable this style for the error messages that we show when there is a problem.